# SQL syntex issue when running query in python with pandas.read_sql

Tags: python, postgresql

The code works yesterday, I don't know why it suddenly shows me a syntax error. I tried restart the jupyter notebook, it doesn't fix it.

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import yaml

with open("credentials.yml", 'r') as f:
    config = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
conn = psycopg2.connect(
   database=config['db']['database'], user=config['db']['username']
    , password=config['db']['password'], host=config['db']['server'], port= config['db']['port']
)

pd.read_sql(f"""select * from myschema.mytable limit 100""", conn)
```

The syntax error is pointing to the last `"`, just before `,` at this line `pd.read_sql(f"""select * from myschema.mytable limit 100""", conn)`

The SQL is postgresql

Comment: You're using an older version of Python that doesn't support F-strings.  Remove the `f` from in front of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "select * from myschema.mytable limit 100"
pd.read_sql(s, conn)
```